# Change scrollbar color in Android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

Is it possible to change the color or appearance of the scrollbar in a ScrollView or ListView?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check out the ApiDemos sample project in the SDK. The layout `res/layout/scrollbar2.xml` shows a way to style scroll bars.

There are separate attributes for the scrollbar track and the scrollbar thumb. Size can also be adjusted.

Comment: Good sir, I salute you! For other people searching the same answer: Just do android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb" and let scrollbar_vertical_thumb be a gradient :)

Comment: `<ListView android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb" />` in the Drawable: `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#6699FF"
        android:startColor="#3333FF" />

    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

    <size android:width="1dp" />

</shape>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @CelticParser

Comment: Thanks a lot, @CelticParser. Working like a charm.

Answer (score 85):

You can set Listview property as

```
android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
```

Here **custom_scroll_style** is a xml file under the drawable folder. Lets create the custom_scroll_style.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#FF3401"
    android:centerColor="#ff5c33"
    android:startColor="#FF3401" />

<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<size android:width="4dp"/>
<padding
    android:left="0.5dp"
    android:right="0.5dp" />

</shape>
```

Here I got a Orange color scrollbar. You can use images also if the image size is less than 2px instead of xml.

Comment: Use `@color/` for color. Example: `@color/white` Otherwise it's a great answer.

Comment: Which directory should I put `custom_scroll_style.xml` in? Drawables? Styles?

Comment: you should add it in drawable folder. if it not exist create folder called drawable under resources(res) directory and add custom_scroll_style in it.