# Is there a way change ListView scroll color?

Tags: android, android-layout

i am using ListView and I am trying change scroll color but no result, I don't know how to do it, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean Scroll Bar color.. [If yes check here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3071068/593709)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071068/change-scrollbar-color-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Try this

android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white"

Comment: it does work, but makes my scrollbar very dick and to display as soon as the view is loaded, very odd.

I fix it with this,

android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/colorWhite"
android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="0"

Answer (score 2):

If you mean background color of listview when drawing then see [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html) android blog post..

If you mean scrollbar color then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071068/change-scrollbar-color-in-android) SO thread...