# In a ScrollView, can I make the scrollable edges glow constantly?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a help screen that comes up before my android game starts. It's a ScrollView. While playtesting, I found that almost without fail the players would tap on the screen at various points until they accidentally moved the screen a bit. Then they realized it was scrollable.

This isn't a good experience. I want the scrollable edge of the screen to glow constantly so that it's obvious that you need to scroll. Simply showing the scrollbar doesn't help because it's so minimalist. Even if it's wider I'm not sure it would attract the eye enough to clue people into the need to scroll.

Is this possible to do or do I need to derive my own version of ScrollView? If the latter, what do I need to do to make the edge glow?

Answer (score 1):

One way, theoretically, is to use:

```
yourScrollView.setOverScrollMode(ScrollView.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS); // android:overScrollMode="always" in XML
```

However, I've had no luck with this feature (at least with vertical `ScrollView`s). Instead, I would recommend adding an arrow down the side of your page, or some text that says "scroll down". This way, it will blend in nicely with your app.

Alternately, you could make the scrollbars more visible (perhaps bright pink!) by employing [this tactic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071068/change-scrollbar-color-in-android) (the article is on `ListView`s, but it should work for a `ScrollView` too), in addition to [always showing scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702502/how-to-always-show-scrollbar).