# Change the truck color of a listview in android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, scrollbar

I'm not sure if it's called the truck in the world of java, but I've always referred to the scroll bar size thing as a truck.  That bit on the right that gets smaller as there are more items in the list, and that stays relative to the current scroll position.  Truck?  Right?

Well regardless of what it's called, does anyone know how to change it from white to another color.   I've a list with green text in it, and in fact all my controls are green on a black background.  It looks quite spunky and fun.  But for the "truck"; it remains white.

Does anyone know how to change the truck color?

Answer (score 1):

> Just do
>   android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
>   and let scrollbar_vertical_thumb be a gradient

refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071068/change-scrollbar-color-in-android)