# Android ListView thumb ScrollBar

Tags: android, listview

**I want to see the following thumb scrollbar:**

http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/scroll-thumb

**What I am seeing is:**

[image]

**My XML Layout is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxaassss"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Java code** in onCreate of Activity class (I am extending from Activity class and not ListActivity):

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoriesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<119;i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_ID, String.valueOf(i));
            //map.put(KEY_TITLE, "hello");
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, Prayer.tip.getNthLine(i, true).replace("~", ""));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, "");
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, "");
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, String.valueOf(getResources().getIdentifier("img" + i, "drawable", getPackageName())));
            categoriesList.add(map);

        }
        LazyAdapter adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, categoriesList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

I haven't posted code of LazyAdapter as I think it has nothing to do with the styling of that fast thumb scrollbar. If required, I can post that code too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071068/change-scrollbar-color-in-android

Comment: You are seeing that scrollbar thumb because you are running your app on Android 4.0 or above. The thumb in the link is from Android 2.3. You can get that image and use it from link @Brijesh posted above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your xml code like this

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"`enter code here`
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxaassss"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="#FFF"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    style="@style/CustomTheme"
    android:scrollX="0px"
    android:scrollY="0px"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarSize="20dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

and in your style

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scroll_track</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scroll_thumb</item>
```

like in manifest

`<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">`

Comment: I added this code but error in styles.xml is reported. Is there any place where I can get scroll_track and scroll_thumb images

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb`" and create a drawable as per your need.

Like

```
<ListView android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb" />
```

in the Drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <gradient android:angle="0" android:endColor="#6699FF" android:startColor="#3333FF" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" /> 
    <size android:width="1dp" /> 
</shape>
```

I think this is what you want!