# How to Stop Scroll of list view and how to scroll list view with Button in Android?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a question. How should i stop scroll of list view in android as I want to scroll only with two buttons as named "up" and "down"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider searching before asking a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613844/scrolling-listview-with-buttons

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass your ListView and override the below method:

```
@Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
   if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
      return true;    
   }

   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(e); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can handle by properties of list views to manage scrolling features

```
// to stop the scrolling of list view
listView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); 

//to move to the specified specific position in listview
 listView.setSelection(listItemposition)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to select rows from your ListView you can use:

```
listview.setEnabled(false)
```

Else, you need to override dispatchTouchEvent :

```
@Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
   if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
      return true;    
   }
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(e); 
}
```

Then, to implement your buttons you can use :

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```