# how to change color of the actual scroll in ScrollView android?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-xml

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the color of the ScrollView.

I'm not referring to the background color or the edges.
I attached a print screen of the bar I'm referring. For me, it's kind of transparnt.

Here's how I defined it in the xml:

```
<ScrollView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/personalscores_BackButton" 
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp" >
```

[image: scroll bar]

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Create a scroll bar in drawable(scrollbar.xml) using this

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
         android:angle="45"
         android:centerColor="#65FF8215"
         android:endColor="#87FD2125"
         android:startColor="#65FF8215" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

and add this scroll bar like `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"` to your ListView

**OR**

put the following attribute to your layout

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white"
```

**OR**

create a image and put it in drawable. then add the following property to your layout

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_bar_vertical"
```

Comment: I don't get how to use the xml code you gave. Should that be the entire xml file?

Comment: thanks ! that's exacly what i was looking for. Mike, that's an entire xml file, here's the exact way to use it :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#474946"
        android:centerColor="#ff0000"
        android:endColor="#181818"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>

Comment: @dusm ahhh so like the other answer. Good question.

Comment: Wow... amazing solution! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 43):

put the following attribute to your layout

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white"
```

or create a image and put it in drawable. then add the following property to your layout

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_bar_vertical"
```

Comment: Do you know how to change the thickness of the scrollbar?

Comment: Using the color directly did work for me on ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH but not on GINGERBREAD. For GINGERBREAD I had to define a drawable as described in the answer by Adhikari and wrap the shape in an <item>.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

Comment: this was really helpful! tysm

Answer (score 13):

Try this beautiful custom scrollview

Add following tags in your scrollview

```
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollview_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/vertical_scrollview_track"
```

**Create following drawable in your drawable folder**

***scrollview_thumb.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused" />
<corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

***vertical_scrollview_traack.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="#E2E0EB" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#b3a9a9" />
<size android:width="15dp" />
<corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071068/change-scrollbar-color-in-android):

You can set Listview property as or put the following attribute to your scrollview:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
```

Here **custom_scroll_style** is a xml file under the drawable folder. Lets create the custom_scroll_style.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:endColor="#FF3401"
android:centerColor="#ff5c33"
android:startColor="#FF3401" />

<corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Do you know how to change the thickness of the scrollbar?

Comment: @mike yaworski This link may be help to you:[custom-scrollbar-graphics-in-android](http://porcupineprogrammer.blogspot.in/2012/08/custom-scrollbar-graphics-in-android.html)

Comment: @mikeyaworski You can use android:scrollbarSize to change width of vertical scrollbar and height of horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: "**how to change color**"

The only correct answer is **one**! code line in your layout:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white"
```

Thats all!

p.s.
The question is simple: "color"! and the answer is very simple too.
Not a: "how to set custom bar", "how to change bar sizes" or etc.
Why so many long answers...

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20781845/2227743) (the second example).

Comment: The question is simple and solution is very! simple - Dont need any second or third examples. I don't want and don't need to read all these variants. Just one line of code -That All.