# Error: Color types not allowed (at 'scrollbarThumbVertical' with value '#FFAAFF00')

Tags: android, scrollview

I saw this link: [how to change color of the actual scroll in ScrollView android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781788/how-to-change-color-of-the-actual-scroll-in-scrollview-android)

Then I used `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"`

Then I used `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="#FFAAFF00"`
but I saw this error:
`Color types not allowed (at 'scrollbarThumbVertical' with value '#FFAAFF00')`

Why is this error issued?

Why not use every color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your color value inside `colors.xml` file

```
<color name="light_green">#FFAAFF00</color>
```

and in your layout

```
 android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/light_green
```